# Div reorder with unequal height in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I know there are possible duplicates on this question but I cant find a solution that fits what my problem needs.

I have a layout here that needs to be reorder from medium screens below.

Large screens.
[image: col-lg*]
Iwant it this way when it detects the screen is medium or below

[image]
Iam using bootstrap 3 and this is my HTML layout

```
<div class="row padding-none">
   <div class="col-lg-3 padding-none">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-9">
  <div class="row padding-none">
           <div class="col-lg-10">
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2">
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I had looked up to the bootstrap documentation regarding `push pull` but I cant get it to work. I want only the black and orange to be switch position on medium screens and below.

Sorry for the large space, I cant delete. :) Thank you.

Comment: Voted it down with no comment or reason why they do that :( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by having the orange section first and black section second in the markup. Then add `float:right` to both so that it swaps the position visually. You can target different mediums with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and remove the `float: right` for smaller mediums.
Also you can [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries).

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row padding-none">
    <div class="col-lg-3 padding-none grey">section1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="row padding-none">
            <div class="col-lg-2 orange">section 3</div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 black">section 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.orange, .black {
    float:right;
}
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .orange, .black {
        float: none
    }
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .orange, .black {
        float: none
    }
}
@media(min-width:992px) {
    .orange, .black {
        float: none
    }
}
@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .orange, .black {
        float: right
    }
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/eLy8n/14/)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I use media screens but not changing the htnl mackup. Anyway thank you!