# header + sidebar (half page / full height) + google map (half page / full height)

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to do a template with a

header + sidebar (half page / full height) + google map (half page / full height)

In the jsfiddle, is difficult to see the details, but gives me a scrollbar in the side of the browser which I don't want. Besides, the Sidebar is 40px higher (the header's height) than what's supposed to be. And the google map doesn't reach the bottom. So, even though it has height 100%, it's shorter.

I tried to put them in a container, and managed to make it work with a floating header, but it was cutting off the top of the sidebar and the map, which is not ideal.

http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/TW4uQ/1/

```
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-height:100%;
  }
  #map-canvas {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
    float:left;
  }
  #sidebar{
  background-color:grey;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  }
  #header{
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  }

<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you need some level of scrolling for when the content exceeds the viewport height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="nav">nav</div>
    </div><!-- header -->
    <div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar">sb</div>
    <div id="map">map</div>
    </div><!-- main -->
    </div><!-- page -->
```

```
  html, body {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
#page {
  display:table;
  border-spacing:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#header {
  display:table-row;
}
#main {
  display:table-row;
  position:relative;
}
#nav {
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:40px;
}
#sidebar, #map-canvas {
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;   
  top:40px;
}
#sidebar {
  background:blue;
   left:0;

}
#map-canvas {
    overflow:hidden;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XB5Lp/1/

Comment: o ffs. What are the rules for posting code on SO again?

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I didn't know you could use display:table.

Comment: Yeah, it works for >=IE8 and all. Also, you could check out the updated version.

Comment: I've been trying to integrate it with bootstrap, but I realised it doesn't adapt to small screens (iPhone). The display: table keeps it as a table. I tried with Float:left; but ended up with my original issue.

Comment: Change the display table-cell to block via the corresponding media query.

Comment: Cool, thanks, found this which explains how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries

Comment: as you mentioned at the begining, I need some level of scrolling. And I don't manage to do so. It worked before, but now since the sidebar is absolute, the inner scrolling doesn't work. I updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/XB5Lp/2/

Comment: overflow-y:auto on #sidebar.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I was trying to have the scrollbar hidden. Like in here: http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/NLMuk/1/ but inside your new absolute sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/XB5Lp/3/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Isn't this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ZetvJ/1/ ?

Comment: yes, but without the scrolling. Like I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/NLMuk/1/ but I don't manage to do it inside your sidebar (because it's absolute).

Comment: I found a dirty way to do so, http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/ZetvJ/3/ (I just increased the size of the map_canvas to 52%, so it covers the scrolling ;o) thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I would advise you not to use a "dirty" way. Am I correct when I say you'd like to allow scrolling but want to hide the scroll bar?

Comment: Well, the overflow-y:auto should hide the scrollbar when the maximum allowed height isn't exceeded. If you want to hide the scrollbar when the content does overflow (not recommended), you could get away with a right padding and negative right margin of about 22px on the sidebar with overflow-x:hidden. Maybe add an extra container for more control. You could also check into as less obtrusive, JS based, scrollbar solution as on http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ (requires reading and setting height)

Comment: I tried the padding and margin, and worked perfectly in jsfiddle. but in my bootstrap for some reason it pads towards inside. so it doesn't work. Why is the 52% width worse than the padding?

Comment: Just personal preference, I guess. I'd be pissed off to no end if I intended it for to be 50/50 and had to settle for something other than that. (:

Comment: I understand, I don't like it either, but the other solution doesn't work with bootstrap. Actually, I tried the media query, and changing it to block or inline doesn't work. Thanks a lot for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219612/media-query-responsive-css-diplay-table-to-block-or-inline-disappearing-with-sm

Comment: I get this error ReferenceError: google is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some kind of wrapper ? also the sidebar is longer becourse its 100% and the canvas is 90%.

When using a wrapper try `overflow: hidden`