# @media query responsive CSS diplay table to block or inline disappearing with small screen

Tags: html, css

In this example with responsive CSS, the display:table to block or inline makes the div's disappear.

UPDATED: simplified the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/434ja/1/

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    #sidebar, #map_canvas, #main, #header,#nav {
      display:block !important;
    }
}
```

UPDATED:
They shouldn't disappear, instead they should act as div blocks, and pile up. So, what am I doing wrong. when I check console, it says they are still display:table.

Comment: I fail to see your point? Is this a lesson? Its working as intended.

Comment: It indeed dissapears to me when I minimize the browser window.

Comment: @Ruddy I assume the disappearing of the elements is *not* how it should work. I'm at school on IE9 atm, and it does seem to disappear when resized to a smaller size.

Comment: Just a quick note about CSS comments: your double-slash (single-line) comment won't work in CSS. it will be recognised as a style, not a comment. This would result in your border-top-color style to return an error. You should always use `/* */` comments in CSS.

Comment: @Joeytje50, thanks for spotting that out, I changed it, but still not working. I updated the question, to clarify all the doubts and simplified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the media rule kicks in and removes the table display, `position: absolute` kicks in and moves the elements off screen. So remove the `position: absolute` or do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    #sidebar, #map_canvas, #main, #header,#nav {
      display:block !important;
      position: static;
    }
}
```