# How i can create responsive header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have some knowledge in css and html but new in responsive design.

I have an header i want to create that header responsive . I need some guidelines for this.
I am using bootstrap row and columns but in responsive right side content shifted in new row.
I want in same line in min 320px width also.

Mobile header:

[image]

Desktop header:[image]

I need some guidelines how i can achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using media quires

```
 @media(max-width:767px){}
 @media(min-width:768px){}
 @media(min-width:992px){}
 @media(min-width:1200px){}
```

reference link [Twitter Bootstrap 3: how to use media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using bootstrap, you can use `col-sm-*` and `col-md-*` for other responsive features.

For a navbar, they already have built in responsive functionality.

[Look at this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/render/127023)  which just has the default bootstrap navbar.

Look at the code (take away `/render` in the URL) and then work from there.

Answer (score 0):

you might be using bootstrap 3.

The right side content might getting shifted to new line because of space issues. Bootstrap has the navbar-collapse class for handling this issue.

Read this link:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar