# How to apply style only to particular screen type in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a general style definition as

```
.main-site-nav li a {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Now want to apply a different style only for `.main-site-nav li a` in extra small screens (xs) only as follows.

```
/* xs screens only */
.main-site-nav li a {
    padding-left: 15;
}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Research “CSS media queries”.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The selectors used in BS3 (v3.2.0), if you want to stay consistent:

```
@media(max-width:767px){
  .main-site-nav li a {
    padding-left: 15;
  }
}
```

This will take care of your xs screen

refer : [Twitter Bootstrap 3: how to use media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries)

Answer (score 2):

Use media queries like below. I have assumed your small screen resolution is 500px.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 500px)
 {
   .main-site-nav li a {
     padding-left: 15;
   }
 }
```

You can also specify `min-width` and `max-width` like below.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 380px)
 {
   .main-site-nav li a {
     padding-left: 15;
   }
 }
```

[**Read more about media queries here.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)