# Re-ordering bootstrap columns on desktop and mobile views

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically, I want a certain column (search) on the right sidebar to be on top when on mobile devices and still maintain the right sidebar on desktop views.

So here's what I have so far..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 content col-md-pull-3">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">C</div>
</div>
```

It looks like this on mobile (which is what I want)

```
| B |
| A |
| C |
```

However, on desktop, it looks like this (there's a gap between B and C which I don't want)

```
| A | B |
| A |   |
|   | C |
```

Here's how it looks: http://www.codeply.com/go/guzmu84ybo

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like the second structure in Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/5v9bsQfwQg

Comment: It does if A's content is long enough.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I need to sign up to save the code snippet. Here you go, http://www.codeply.com/go/guzmu84ybo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rearranging the structure and using the `flexbox` concept to reorder the columns in mobile devices:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-9 one">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 two">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 three">C</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .one {
    order: 2;
  }

  .two {
    order: 1;
  }

  .three {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

[**CodePly**](http://www.codeply.com/go/mPUM0bIvEH)

Comment: awesome! exactly what I was looking for. I chose this over the other one because it seems more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

[**Working Codeply Solution**](http://www.codeply.com/go/OI9Xy0Jm4r)

Though flexbox might be the most modern approach to this flow issue, some may be looking for a simple 'Bootstrappy' solution or for a solution that will work in IE10+. A single media query will solve your issue and you can remove all the `push`/`pull` classes.  You can simplify your markup to:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="searchWrap" class="col-md-3">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum... This content can be long now... </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this single media query is needed in your CSS to effectively 'reset' the `left` property that was causing all your issues:

```css
@media (min-width : 992px) { 
    #searchWrap { 
        float: right;
        left: 0px; 
    }
}
```

You can change the `992px` to whatever width you'd like the search to flow to the top at. But 992px is the width in Bootstrap 3's grid for 'tablet width' and is most likely the appropriate width for this re-flow to happen. (See all the Bootstrap 3 grid widths [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries).)