# Why is Bootstrap's CSS cutting off the content on my page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to build a webpage. The page looks as it should on desktops and laptops. However, when viewed on mobile phones, the bottom half of the page's content is cutoff. This happens **only** on mobile phones or windows resized smaller than 991px wide.

I tried sifting through the included Bootstrap CSS file but couldn't find any style rules dictating any behaviors like the one I describe.

I've attached two screenshots: Fig. 1 is the intended behavior--the content ends with the embedded contact form. Fig. 2 is the puzzling behavior--the page just ends in the middle of the pricing table.

The site is grillemasters.info

[Fig. 1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH7MB.png
[Fig. 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2190.png

Comment: It's tough to tell from your screenshots what's going on.  It's not an apples-to-apples comparison.  Posting your relevant code or creating a fiddle would be helpful.  Also, read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries) to learn about BS media queries.  Sounds like you are hitting a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more information (e.g. try to post the minimum amount of HTML that still exhibits this error) it's hard to prescribe a solution. But here are three possible things to check out:

- **Mismatched (Incomplete) DOM**
  If you have an open-element (e.g. `<div>`) without its close (`</div>`), HTML behaves in mysterious and often irreproducible ways. This often includes mis-styling all elements after the mismatch.
- **Bad Character or Incomplete File**
  If you are uploading via FTP and the connection is interrupted, you may only be looking at a fragment of the file. Try deleting and re-uploading. The same thing would happen if the browser or FTP client encountered a character that made it stop reading the file — *both* of which might lead to a mismatched DOM.
- **Unnecessary `body` CSS**
  Make sure you don't specify the `height` of `body` or `html` anywhere (or any other global, all-containing elements). The page should flow naturally, without you specifying a `height: 100%.`

**[EDIT]** I looked at your site (which redirects to http://www.supsean.com/grillemasters/, in case others are interested in debugging *outside* a frame). Look at the top of your page when you resize the screen to such a small size; there are quite pervasive CSS issues, likely caused by `position: fixed` or `absolute`s where they needn't be.

Try resolving that, and I suspect you'll stumble across the solution to this question as well.