# Hiding a PHP element using css (WordPress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile

I'm working on a website for a friend, everything goes well so far, but there's one little thing I can't seem to figure out.
I have included SmartSlider 2, which I want to hide on mobile devices. But since SS2 doesn't natively support this I tried by editing the code. Long story short, it won't work.

I've tried including the CSS in the file itself (header.php) :

```
<div class="slider" style="@media(max-width:1120px;){.slider {display:none;}}">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider2 slider="2"]'); ?>
</div>
```

For some reason, it still shows up, hopefully you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try it with the same values for max-width which are use in Bootstrap. See Herr for the values: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18850777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work like you are trying.

you have to put this in custom css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1120px) {
    .slider {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

and remove from here

```
<div class="slider">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider2 slider="2"]'); ?>
</div>
```

and in media query CSS you have `;` here `@media(max-width:1120px;` it's wrong

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrd68p67/1/)

Comment: That did the job, I'm still getting used to the responsive stuff, thanks a lot :)