# Modify extra large container padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/A72aT/2/)  Bootstrap v1

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn">
            Hello
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

...

```
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I have my resolution at 1920 x 1080.  Once we get near this 1900 width the margin gets to be too much.  How can I modify the padding for the container to be less at high resolution?

Comment: I do not think `.container` padding changes, do you mean margin?

Comment: @tmg - yes, I will update this.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the margin settings using the media queries like in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424798/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-use-media-queries)