# how to create an auto-collapsing side-nav

Tags: vuejs2, vue-material

The site for vue-material has a very nice `side-nav` which collapses when the window gets to narrow. How is this done?

`side-nav` when window is wide:
[image]

collapsed `side-nav` when window is narrow :
[image]

Comment: Why not take a look at the repository and the code for the docs website, it is all there if you can make some sense of the relative parts? https://github.com/marcosmoura/vue-material/tree/master/docs/src

Comment: Also, i'm not quite sure if you're referring to the side nav its self as this is a component of vue-material or if you mean simply adjusting what happens when the width of the display / viewport changes as this is relative to css media queries. Here is a link which covers the ones that bootstrap uses to achieve its "responsive" layouts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18850777/2110294