# How to make nav wider css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this footer and inside I've got a nav that I am trying to make a both top navbar and footer sidebar I would like to have them a little wider. How to achieve this?

```
<footer class="footer">

<div class="container" id="maincontainer">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-success navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand">
            <i class="fas fa-car-crash"></i>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="home" asp-action="index">| Registered Brokers |</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your css if you has one.

Comment: use container-fluid class

Comment: @Sergiu, how much wider? whole page? also as asked above add complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width is defined by [Bootstrap's `.container`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#containers). You can also replace it by `.container-xl` or something similar to modify the behavior on different viewpoints. Please have a look at this table, which was retrieved from the above posted link:

[image: Table with .container behavior for different device's width]

To add another maximum width for large devices `> 1200px` (have a look at the different media queries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850777/3623608)), you need to add a custom class like `.custom-container` and overwrite the `max-width` accordingly to your wished width like this:

```
<div class="container custom-container" id="maincontainer">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-success navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand">
            <i class="fas fa-car-crash"></i>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="home" asp-action="index">| Registered Brokers |</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .custom-container {
        max-width: 1200px !important; // Your custom value
    }
}
```

If you always want to define the width to `100%` of the window, replace `.container` by `.container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-fluid {
width: 80% !important;
```

}

This helped me.[image]
Thanks to @shahryar-mohajer